# Is there a way to completely disable TCP keepalive?

Tags: linux, tcp, keepalive

I'm trying to disable TCP Keepalive in a linux machine.

If I set the three keepalive parameters to 0, the machine refuses connections.

`sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=0`

`sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=0`

`sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=0`

If I just change `tcp_keepalive_time`, calling `netstat --timers` shows this:

> Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
>   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Timer
>
> tcp        0      0 IP.IP.IP.IP:ssh        IP.IP.IP.IP:57609      ESTABLISHED keepalive (70.48/0/0)

Comment: SSH configures its keepalives internally: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/keep-your-linux-ssh-session-from-disconnecting/?PageSpeed=noscript . Many opinions online indicate that it would be an absolutely terrible idea to set no keepalives with SSH in particular, and will cause sessions to hang, and orphaning server side sessions from their client, such that the user session never expires server-side. http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for the info. I'm trying to achieve it for other connections, the netstat capture just happens to be an SSH connection that I was running at the time. I've had a few ideas to check from your comment... thx!